# How to monitor apache server is running or not on aws?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS and need to monitor Apache running or not. Is there any way to monitor it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor production services (tomcat, MSQL and apache) using amazon ec2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275041/monitor-production-services-tomcat-msql-and-apache-using-amazon-ec2)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at CloudWatch Logs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html). It allows you to connect (operational) logs to AWS CloudWatch and define alerts on events your can see in these logs. These alerts can be sent as email, as long as you know how to define them well.

If you have some external service that is pinging your service every few minutes for latency monitoring, you can monitor inactivity on these logs, as you are not sure that an error will appear if the server is just stuck.

You might also want to use Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) in front of your server. It will allow you to scale later on, but it can also perform health check to your server and even replace it with Auto Scaling functionality (with min and max values set to 1 - Auto Healing). See here for more details on Health Check setting in ELB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-healthcheck.html